# Best way to achieve this sort of workflow in C++?

Tags: c++, string, istringstream

I am doing this problem: 
https://leetcode.com/problems/verify-preorder-serialization-of-a-binary-tree/

My approach is to assign serialized string to a stream like "1,#,2,#,#".
And then read a character from stream. If it is a '#', return. Else,
visit left and right child.

```
class Solution {
    stringstream pre; int char_count = 0;
public:
    bool visit() {
        if (char_count >= pre.str().size()) return 0;
        char key; char comma;
        while (char_count < pre.str().size() && pre.peek() != ',') {
            pre >> key;
            char_count++;
        }
        if (pre.peek() == ',') {
            pre >> comma;
            char_count++;
        }
        if (key == '#') return 1;

        return visit() && visit();
    }

    bool isValidSerialization(string preorder) {
        pre << preorder;
        cout << "preorder: " << preorder << endl;
        if (!visit()) return 0;
        if (pre.str().size() > char_count) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution q;
    cout << q.isValidSerialization("1,#,#");
}
```

Earlier, I was checking for

```
if (!pre.str().size())
```

because I wrongly expected stream to delete the extracted characters. Now I am maintaining char_count but the code is no longer elegant. Is there any way to simplify this in C++.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: shouldn't it be 33 after I have extracted 1 character from stream.

Comment: `stringbuf::str()` returns the entire underlying buffer. Try doing `q_s.str().substr(q_s.tellg())`

Comment: Thanks. So the underlying buffer never erases any data. If I loop with inserting ( << ) one character and extracting one character, will the buffer grow to infinite size?

Comment: Any other stream container where I can do q_s.str() without tellg.?

Comment: A cheap hack: `std::getline(a_stream, a_string, '\0')` (read until you find a NULL character.) It's a hack because it's possible you might have a NULL character in the stream. That the stream never really empties is a good thing to remember though, You have to empty it periodically with something along the lines of `str("")` (reset the underlying buffer to an empty string) or the stream will get very, very large.

Comment: Thanks. Can I selectively remove only the characters I have extracted (not resetting the entire stream to "". I do this in the while loop and my terminating condition is that  stringstream.str().size() is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). There is no overload for the `operator>>(char)`, it is likely being implicitly cast to something else. This is the expected behaviour of the code you have written.

Comment: When I change it to int key;  I still see after: 333. I expected nothing as I have already extracted the integer. From the comment I came to know that it returns entire underlying buffer.